# Formulario html com código PHP para inserir no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou começando agora com HTML, PHPe MySQL com o Sublime utilizando o XAMPP.

Estou fazendo um formulário teste em HTML para incluir direto no MySQL.

Porem não está incluindo os dados.

Já fiz vários testes, inclusive esse último copiei da internet, e mesmo assim não inclui no formulário.

Código do formulário:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Testando conexão ao banco de dados </title>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Formulário de Cadastro de Clientes</h3><br>
  <form name="Cadastro" action="cadastrar.php" method="POST">
    <label>Nome do Cliente: </label>
    <input type="text" name="NomeCliente" size="30"><br>
    <label>Sobrenome do Cliente: </label>
    <input type="text" name="SobrenomeCliente" size="45"><br>
    <label>Sexo do Cliente: </label>
    <select name="Sexo">
      <option value="M">Masculino</option>
      <option value="F">Feminino</option>
      <option value="N">Não Declarado</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Código PHP que faz a conexão com o banco:

```
<?php
$nome = $_POST['NomeCliente'];
$sobrenome = $_POST['SobrenomeCliente'];
$sexo = $_POST['Sexo'];
$strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','cadastro') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
$sql = "INSERT INTO banco_teste VALUES ";
$sql .= "('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$sexo')"; 
mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
mysqli_close($strcon);
echo "Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!";
echo "<a href='formulario.html'>Clique aqui para realizar um novo cadastro</a><br>";
echo "<a href='consulta.php'>Clique aqui para realizar uma consulta</a><br>";
?>
```

Quando incluo dados no formulário aparece isso na tela e não insere os dados no phpMyAdmin:

```
<?php
$nome = $_POST['NomeCliente'];
$sobrenome = $_POST['SobrenomeCliente'];
$sexo = $_POST['Sexo'];
$strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','cadastro') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'banco_teste' VALUES ";
$sql .= "('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$sexo')"; 
mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
mysqli_close($strcon);
echo "Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!";
echo "<a href='formulario.html'>Clique aqui para realizar um novo cadastro</a><br>";
echo "<a href='consulta.php'>Clique aqui para realizar uma consulta</a><br>";
?>
```

Comment: Aparece-te o código php quando abres a página no browser? Como estás a aceder a página? Qual o endereço que tens no navegador?

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que na sua `query` você não está declarando aonde os dados serão inseridos.

Como está:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'banco_teste' VALUES ";
$sql .= "('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$sexo')";
```

Como deve ser:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'banco_teste'(nome, sobrenome, sexo) VALUES ";
$sql .= "('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$sexo')";
```

Comment: Pode ser, mas não é obrigatório especificar quais as colunas em que os valores devem ser inseridos. Se for esse o problema, o resultado final deveria ser `Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro` que é o que está no `die` a seguir a tentar correr a query.

Comment: @Leite claro que é obrigatório, ou você menciona os nomes dos campos desa forma, ou usa o `SET`, mas tem que especificar em qual coluna o conteúdo sera inserido, a não ser que os dados sejam inseridos em todas as colunas.

Comment: Isto já é off-topic. Estava só a tentar ajudar-te. Mas, não é obrigatório não, podes fazer ai o teste. Se forem só aquelas 3 colunas que ele tem na tabela, para que vai precisar especificar?

Comment: Como normalmente o `id` é definido como auto increment, usa-se em casos específicos o insert com essa estrutura.

Comment: @Leite, como eu disse, não é necessário especificar, quando o insert é realizado em todas as colunas da tabela, em uma tabela de cadastro comum, o id é definido como `auto_increment` pois não tem como e nem precisa fazer o controle manual.

Comment: Podes definir o ID como `null` e não sabemos a estrutura da tabela dele.
Imaginemos que o `banco_teste` tem 4 campos sim, `id`, `nome`, `sobrenome` e `sexo`. A query seria `INSERT INTO banco_teste VALUES (NULL, 'Onome', 'Osobrenome', 'Masculino')`

Comment: Mas nesse caso não está definindo como `NULL` :). Enfim, vamos encerrar esse assunto pois está fugindo do contexto do tópico.

Comment: Sim, já é off-topic. Mas! `Null` faz apenas com que o ID seja incrementado, se for `auto-increment` claro

Answer (score 1):

No formulário HTML tem de incluir uma action, como por exemplo:

```
<form action="inserir.php">
<div class="form-group>
   <label for="nomeCliente">Nome do Cliente</label>
   <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome">
</div>
<button type="submit">Inserir</button>
```

Numa pagina chamada de inserir.php tem de colocar o seguinte código:

```
<?php
// LIGAR A BASE DE DADOS
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "nome_da_base_de_dados");

// VERIFICAR CONEXÃO
if($link === false){
    die("ERRO AO LIGAR À BASE DE DADOS. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// ESCAPE INPUTS
$nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['nome']);

// INSERIR DADOS NA TABELA
$sql = "INSERT INTO nome_da_tabela (name) VALUES ('$name')";

// VOLTAR A PAGINA DO FORMULARIO
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    mysqli_close($link);
    header('Location: ../pagina_do_formulario.php');
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Não foi possível adicionar o cliente.";
}
?>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Se quando submetes o formulário, o que te aparece é o código PHP que deveria estar a gravar na base de dados, a forma como deves estar a aceder a página é errada.

Estás a usar um endereco tipo `http://localhost/omeuprojecto/` ou `file:///caminho/para/o/projecto/index.html`?

Se for o 2o, tens de garantir que tens o XAMPP iniciado, e tentar aceder usando `http://localhost/`.

Caso nao funcione, o XAMPP pode estar numa porta diferente, para ver qual a porta, podes abrir o Painel de Controlo do XAMPP e ver ai qual a porta que o Apache está a usar, em principio será `80` e `443`, se for diferente de `80`, por exemplo `81`, terás de usar `http://localhost:81`